# Missing namespace in referenced assembly

Tags: c#, reference, class-library

This is just an info post, because I have been bitten by this too many times.

When you have a large solution with lots of class libraries that reference each other, and you create a new project and reference one of these class libraries but the compiler complains that it can not see a namespace in your referenced assembly.

**Make sure both projects used the same Target platform**

The default platform for a new c# project in VS is .net4 client profile. However, if the assembly you are referencing is importing/using a class library that is not available in the in the client profile version, the compiler can not see the portion of namespace that uses that class lib.

Hope this saves some one some time.

Comment: Please use your blog to post this kind of information. Stack Overflow should be used to ask or answer programming related questions.

Comment: Thanks for you input, but as far as i know there is no way to add "solutions/general info posts on SO", so that they are indexed and searchable by people experiencing issues. I have seen this done before by other users that want to share information and thought it to be standard practice. If there's a better way, please enlighten me.

Comment: no, there's no way to add "solutions/general info" posts on SO because that's not what SO is intended to be used for and that's why this post was closed. It's off-topic. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: funny I thought SO is intended to be a repo of solutions to problems?

Comment: Yes, for programming related problems. You don't have a problem since you already solved it. You should have posted this as a question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add to be aware of weird behavior of Visual studio 2010 convertor (from solution of Visual studio 2008) which edit the target plateform when you switch to .Net 4.0.

You must be careful of the Target Platform :)